# Detecting the user's choice when he sees the tel link popup

Tags: iphone, popup, tel

I wish to know when the users are actually placing a call from my application (UIWebView) and not just tapping on the phone number.

How can I get the result of what the user selected when he receives the call/cancel popup after pressing a telephone link in my app?

Answer (score 0):

There is some info regarding this on [Opening tel: links from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102829/opening-tel-links-from-uiwebview).

> **How Things Work & What You Want**
>
> The OS is not going to handle showing the Call/Cancel alert dialog for you. That is up to you. It shows up in Safari because the Safari app's shouldStartLoadWithRequest method undoubtedly responds to the tel: scheme by showing a UIAlertView. Your conditional for if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) should, when YES, trigger a UIAlertView with a Call and Cancel button. On Call, you will tell the sharedApplication to openURL; on Cancel, you will not issue the call & you will also want to return NO so your app does not attempt to loadWithRequest

Code Example:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
            if (buttonIndex == 1) {
           //OK clicked
          } else {
    }
}
 
- (void) _showAlert:(NSString*)title
{
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Check your networking configuration." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Hope this helped you in some way.

Best Regards

Linus