# Opening tel: links from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I've searched and searched, but I can't seem to find a fix for this problem.

For some reason, I can not get 'tel:' links to work in a UIWebView.  When the links are clicked, the message "The URL can't be shown" appears.  Clicking on the same link in Safari works perfectly and dials the number.

This problem started with iOS 5.  These links worked perfectly in iOS 4.2 and 4.3.

I'm not sure what other information might be useful, so please let me know if I need to clarify.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the actual code in use...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;    

    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (![url.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            return NO; // Let OS handle this url
        }
    }

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startBusy) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

If I take out the first if statement, the number gets dialed immediately with no confirmation.  I'd really like it to function the way it used to by giving an alert, giving you the option to hit either 'Call' or 'Cancel' before dialing the number.

Comment: make sure is there any special characters or not?

Comment: @Hitman Yes - the links look like tel:########## (With actual numbers, and not the hash symbol).  Some have dashes, but whether or not they are included doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If launching as an HTML link, the tel URL scheme will be opened if they appear as:

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

If you are launching from a native URL string (meaning you coded this in Objective-C and are not serving it via a WebView), your URL string should look like this:

```
tel:1-408-555-5555
```

**Note:** This only works with iOS devices that have the Phone app installed (that means *iPhone* only). iPad & iPod Touch devices will display a warning message.

**Note 2:** Ensure the phone numbers you are passing do not contain spaces or other special characters (such as * and #).

**Code Feedback**

Based on your code, things are a bit clearer now. You comment about how nothing happens when you leave the first `if` statement in the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method (where you return `YES`). This is exactly the behavior you *should* see because your app is not the Phone app. Only the Phone app can handle the `tel:` URL scheme. By returning `YES`, you are telling the OS that your app will handle the phone call, but it cannot. You get the call when that conditional is removed because the next block, which checks `if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])` allows the `sharedApplication` (which, in this case, is the Phone app) to launch the call.

**How Things Work & What You Want**

The OS is not going to handle showing the Call/Cancel alert dialog for you. That is up to you. It shows up in Safari because the Safari app's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method undoubtedly responds to the `tel:` scheme by showing a `UIAlertView`. Your conditional for `if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"])` should, when `YES`, trigger a `UIAlertView` with a Call and Cancel button. On Call, you will tell the `sharedApplication` to `openURL`; on Cancel, you will not issue the call & you will also want to return `NO` so your app does not attempt to `loadWithRequest`.

**Self-Correcting Edit**

To be fair about errors in my own thought process, I'm leaving my responses above.

I believe the Call/Cancel dialog is, in fact, a feature of the OS. Apologies for the inaccuracy.

I'd also erroneously glanced over your code's passing off URL handling to sharedApplication only occurring when the scheme was `http` or `https`.

After another look at the code, I wonder if, by any chance you have debug options on in Safari? I believe this prevents the alert from popping up. Also--just to double-check the obvious--you aren't trying this inside the simulator, correct? What happens if you remove the conditional check for `http`/`https` and just use the `canOpenURL` check?

However, aside from the error in my comments on the conditional & dialog itself, you still should not be returning `YES`. To make a phone call, you should only be able to pull that off by passing it to `sharedApplication:openURL` and ensuring you return `NO` because your app is not the Phone app. The only reason you'd want to return `YES` in this method is if your app is going to handle a `tel:` link in a special way that doesn't involve sending it to the Phone app.

Comment: The HTML link in your example is what we are doing.  As I mentioned, it used to work before iOS 5, so it is unlikely that would be the issue anyhow.  The links do work fine in Safari - if the links were not formatted in that way, Safari wouldn't work either.  Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Care to share some actual code of how you're handling the UIWebView in your application? Can you launch other URL schemes successfully from your app's UIWebView? EDIT: More specifically, are you handling the shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType method in your UIWebViewDelegate to properly launch the link outside your app?

Comment: I edited the question to include the code, as well as a few more details.  Thanks!

Comment: I do have the debugging in Safari disabled, but no popup.  But I'll worry about that at some other time.  Your explanation does help though...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you created the UIWebView in a .xib, select the UIWebView and check its attributes in the Attribute Inspector. The first heading should be 'Web View', and under that it provides a list of checkboxes marked 'Detection'. Ensure that 'Phone Numbers' is checked.

Comment: This doesn't make sense if links, emails and numbers are already added to the `HTML` page using the `anchor` tag